# Summarising an attribute from point layer in polygons with FME

Tags: fme-form, statistics, overlay

I have a number of polygon feature sets and a point layer containing an attribute with population count. I want to summarise the population attribute for all points within each polygon feature set using FME.

Ie. the end product should be a number of polygon layers with a population attribute.

So in short: How to get the sum of attribute X from all overlapping points in a point dataset, for each out of N polygon feature sets, using FME?

(I'm basically trying to recreate the "Join attributes by location" tool in QGIS with FME.)

Comment: in FME Feature Reader with Intersect (Spatial Filter) & Merge Initiator and Result in Advanced is a fast way to transfer attributes spatially for your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Use the PointOnAreaOverlayer transformer. In the parameters dialog set a list name. The polygon features will emerge with a list of which point features fell inside, including their attributes.

Then use a ListSummer transformer to add up the attribute X in that list.

I put an example workspace (template) on Dropbox at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mbvmfef7tjdqr8/AttributeSummer.fmwt?dl=0

Comment: Works like a charm. However, I neglected to mention that my areas were multipart in my original question. So it might be good for others to know that if you input multipart geometries into the PointOnAreaOverlayer, you need to use an Aggregator at the end to get the original multipart areas. The aggregator can then sum the attribute created by the ListSummer from the single part geometries into the final multipart geometries.